# I have a numpy array, and an array of indexs, how can I access to these positions at the same time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

for example, I have the numpy arrays like this

```
a =
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 3, 2]])
```

and index like this to select the max values

```
max_idx = 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0]])
```

how can I access there positions at the same time, to modify them.
like "a[max_idx] = 0" getting the following

```
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 2]])
```

Comment: I still don't see how to got to the expected output. Care to explain on that? Pseudo code or even a loopy code to explain? Simply stating `a[max_idx] = 0` doesn't give us a good idea on what's in your mind.

Comment: a(0,2) is 3, and a(1, 0) is 4, so putting them together, what I want i a[max_idx] = 0 is to make 3 and 4 to be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `subscripted-indexing` -

```
a[max_idx[:,0],max_idx[:,1]] = 0
```

If you are working with higher dimensional arrays and don't want to type out slices of `max_idx` for each axis, you can use `linear-indexing` to assign `zeros`, like so -

```
a.ravel()[np.ravel_multi_index(max_idx.T,a.shape)] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [28]: a
Out[28]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 3, 2]])

In [29]: max_idx
Out[29]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0]])

In [30]: a[max_idx[:,0],max_idx[:,1]] = 0

In [31]: a
Out[31]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 2]])
```

Comment: this line return [[0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]]

Comment: but not [[1, 2, 0],[0, 3, 1]]

Comment: @user2985656 I misunderstood it before, fixed it.

Comment: but still, I've already got the index array, not using a.argmax(1). cause actually I'm not modifying the max values, max_idx is just an example.

Comment: @user2985656 Edit your question, add in the expected output and explain it.

Comment: I knew it was a stupid question, but it's a little hard to search for such kind of question. May be I should pick up and read some book first~

Comment: @user2985656 Well you can look into [`various modes of indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) as it's all a play of it.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy support [advanced slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) like this:

```
a[b[:, 0], b[:, 1]] = 0
```

Code above would fit your requirement.

If `b` is more than 2-D. A better way should be like this:

```
a[np.split(b, 2, axis=1)]
```

The [np.split](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) will split ndarray into columns.